# possible to force a 64-bit JVM to use 32-bit mode via the argument "-d32"?

Tags: java, deployment, 32bit-64bit

so I have some 3rd party native library that works only in 32 bit JVM across windows,osx,linux and I need to always enforce the java application to run in 32 bit JVM mode.

What about if the target system only has 64-bit JVM installed, would it be possible to force it to run the java application in 32 bit mode?

Comment: @MockerTim: Kim Jong Woo said that his application has a native third party library.  It's not the Java bytecode that's in question here.

Comment: IIRC, only the OS X Java version supports the `-d32` flag.

Comment: You need to be specific.  Is this the Oracle JVM?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

The preconditions that you specified prohibit (okay, I'm precluding the bundle-the-JVM solution and install-the-JVM solution) the application from running in a 32-bit JRE.  If you want to run your application in a 32-bit JVM, and your third party native library is only available as a 32-bit DLL, then you must use a 32-bit JVM.  A 64-bit JVM cannot load the 32-bit library; there is no 32-bit mode to load such libraries.

Solutions include:

- Require the 32-bit JVM to be installed
- Bundle the 32-bit JVM (the three OS's - that'll be a pretty big burden)
- Install the 32-bit JVM for the user
- Use a different third party library / roll your own / find a 64-bit version of the third party library

Comment: As a side note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2925549/314104 discusses a possibility that you might find interesting if you're planning to deploy to a 64-bit Java target anyway.  With two JVMs, one 32-bit and one 64-bit, you can use RMI/CORBA and host a service on the 32-bit JVM which encapsulates the library, and you can still use the 64-bit JVM for your application, drawing the benefits of a 64-bit VM.

Comment: so I guess this means I need to purchase an installer that will bundle the desired JVM.

Comment: That's one way to take it on. You can also use an installer which installs the right JVM for the user from the web if the JVM doesn't exist on the user's computer.

Comment: Are there other ways? The goal is to bundle the 32-bit JRE and make my application use that. possibly somehow copy the 32bit JRE into a folder of my app, write a .bat or .bash file to use that bundled JRE to launch the application?

Comment: For Windows, yes, that's pretty easy. The .cmd batch file would look something like "%~dp0jre\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%~dp0app\main.jar". This only works on modern versions of Windows based on NT. I've been trying to find a good solution for this in *nix, and I haven't found one yet.

Comment: now I just need to find out the batch alternative for Mac and Linux

Comment: The trick i've been using is to generate a .sh script which specifies the installation directory when I unpack the application.  You might want to ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 11):

With Java 6, no. With Java 7+, yes.

Use -d32 with Java 7

Comment: You missed the part where he said "What about if the target system only has 64-bit JVM installed, would it be possible to force it to run the java application in 32 bit mode?".  -d32 still requires a 32-bit JRE.

Comment: With java 1.8 (64bit) I get the following error message:

`java -d32`
`Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.`

Comment: [This Oracle FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_layering) suggests the -d32/-d64 option is only useful on Solaris; on Windows/Linux you need to install the appropriate 32 or 64 bit JVM and specifically run the one you want (e.g. by including it in your system path).

Comment: JDK 10 [removes -d32 option](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html)

Answer (score 1):

> possible to force a 64-bit JVM to use 32-bit mode via the argument
>   “-d32”?

As there is no such argument to the `java` command, the answer is obviously 'no'.

Comment: I don't think you are correct as both `-d32` and `-d64` are documentted here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html