# link 32 bits native language dll on 64 bits os windows

Tags: java, dll, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to use a java program on 64 bits virtual machine windows 7 to process videos. This java program uses a 32 bits dll.
According to  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757456/java-native-interface-32-bit-dll-on-64-bit-system), I installed a 32 bits jvm and according to  [this one](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm), I put the dll in `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64` directory.

I run the program in the command prompt by specifyng the full path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe` of the executable. The java program runs normally, but when it comes to use the functionality provided by the dll, I receive the error message `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Thanks for any advice

Paul

Comment: If `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64` in your `PATH` or your `java.library.path`?

Answer (score 1):

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` means that Java could not find the DLL.

Make sure that the directory that contains the DLL is in the `java.library.path`. You can set this path by specifying it as a system property on the command line, using the `-D` switch, when you start your program. For example:

```
java -Djava.library.path=C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64 com.mypackage.MyMainClass
```