# Should a 32-bit JRE work OK on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit, freeze

I have created a desktop app. Within the bundle, I've included the Windows 32-bit JRE6. We've tested the app on our Windows 64-bit machine and it seems fine, but the app is making our customer's 64-bit Windows machine hang.

Is this hanging problem likely to be that we are trying to run a 32-bit JRE on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Unlikely, because 64-bit Windows machines routinely run 32-bit applications, including 32 bit JREs.

Comment: Downvotes are unnecessary. This is a valid question.

Comment: (At this point, I might make the comment that's it's not the JRE that's making the Windows machine hang, it's the Windows. I guess I just did.)

Comment: It's unlikely the problem you have have something to do with the title of the question. This is an operating system problem, probably too much trash installed on too small machine. If you add more detailed information about configuration, you could post it on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://windows.microsoft.com/en-id/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows-frequently-asked-questions

> Most programs designed for the 32-bit version of Windows will work on
>   the 64-bit version of Windows. Notable exceptions are many antivirus
>   programs.

That being said. For your specific use case it should not be the root cause (like @kocko already said).

However, I'd like to note that if you are executing native code (i.e. using JNI) loading 32-bit native libraries (DLLs) will cause issues on 64-bit machines but generally give you a good stacktrace instead of hanging the whole PC.

Comment: What issues? I've been doing it for years.

Comment: I am talking about the infamous UnsatisfiedLinkError [see this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757456/java-native-interface-32-bit-dll-on-64-bit-system)

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. `64-bit Windows` run `32-bit` applications (as well as `32-bit JRE`) with no problems.

The opposite, however, is not possible.