# How to launch a 32-bit java process from a 64-bit java process without hardcoding paths

Tags: java

I have a 64-bit java application and I would like to run a particular jar application in 32-bit mode. For testing, I have done this in a disposable class:

```
public class Invoke32bit {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe\" -jar C:\\dev\\test.jar");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And it works...but how can I avoid hardcoding the java path? The machines that will be using this application will have both 64-bit and 32-bit JRE's installed (this application is used internally and we don't have to worry about anyone else using it)

One approach I've thought of is to provide a config file to allow users to enter the path to 64-bit and 32-bit java, but if there was a way to automate this that would be better.

Comment: Have you thought of using `args`?

Comment: No, I was not aware there was an argument for calling `Java` in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your point. I could pass in the path to the 32-bit executable, but to me that's still kind of hardcoding it (it's just harcoded somewhere else)

Comment: Passing parameters by external means is not hardcoding, it's configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the java System property `java.home`, but that points to only one installation and there is never any guarantee that there is a 32 bit JRE also present.

You could use the other available system properties to 'crawl' for other, 32-bit JRE installations, but of course that's not fool proof (what if someone decides to install their JRE in some odd place where you are not looking for it?

Alternatively, you could package a 32 bit JRE with your software and invoke that. The obvious drawback is the size of your distribution.

On system properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Related topic: [possible to force a 64-bit JVM to use 32-bit mode via the argument "-d32"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374193/possible-to-force-a-64-bit-jvm-to-use-32-bit-mode-via-the-argument-d32) (it's not possible)

Comment: Those are good things to consider. I will require users to install 32-bit JRE in a predictable location, and require both 64-bit and 32-bit JRE's to be installed.

Comment: In that case, for windows, you only have to anticipate users using different drive letters. That might get tricky too, as technically, any drive can be used to install software on. For example, I do not have my java installations on my C drive. Although it is up to you to decide what 'predictable' means.

Answer (score 0):

Read Oracle Official Tutorial about [Configuration Utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/config.html).

You can use Properties, Command-Line Arguments and/or Environment Variables to mention a few methods.